Meaning of "but" after negation clause
The below usage of "but" seems weird to me. I can guess that it means something like "nevertheless" or "instead", but I'm not sure about it, because "but" is usually used to say that something is different than in previous clause, but in that meaning the sentence  doesn't make sense because its parts contradict to each other. In my opinion to make it consistent "but" should be replaced with "and." What do I miss here? Is there an extra meaning to "but"? or is this some specific usage?

Don't follow your command but I will fight and I will stand

(From the song Angel of Darkness.)

This seems like slightly odd usage. Is this a song lyric by any chance? I believe a more usual way to phrase this would be, "I won't follow your command, but I will fight and I will stand," though your question still applies.

yes, this is lyrics from Angel of Darkness https://genius.com/Alex-c-angel-of-darkness-lyrics

A song by three Germans.

@Astralbee - sounds like a recipe for jollity!

These are song lyrics, a form of poetry, and non-standard usages are common. The meaning can't be known for sure, since the subject of the first clause is missing. It's probably "I," but that's not certain. The whole song makes very little sense and can be understood simply as using phrases for the feelings and images they suggest, rather than to make up meaning. Don't waste too much time treating it as a usage model.

All I see is that the subject (I) is obviously missing from the start of the line. Who knows (or cares) whether that's a typo, done for reasons of scansion, or because it wasn't written by a native Anglophone? It's not really a useful question.

This is a song lyric written by nonnative speakers. Because of that, the way it is phrased is unusual. Instead, English speakers might say something like "I will not follow your command, but I will fight and I will stand."
The use of "but" here is very standard. It indicates a contrast between the two clauses. Saying that "I will not follow your command" or "I will not take orders from you" could be classified as not being helpful. Saying that "I will fight" could be classified as helpful. You could look at the sentence as "I will not do this one helpful thing, but I will do a different helpful thing." Phrased that way, it should be easy to see how the clauses contrast, and why "but" is appropriate and "and" is not.
Here are some similar uses of but:

I will not bake for the party, but I will buy cake.
I won't help set up, but I can lend you some chairs.
I can't attend the fundraiser, but I will donate to the cause.

